# jquery datepicker changing unavailable dates in one instance

Tags: jquery, datepicker

When i am clicking on the button, all datepickers are reloaded and unavailable dates works on all of them, button One should lock unavailable dates only in first datepicker. How to do it? Here is the code

```
function unavailable(date) {
     dmy = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}
var unavailableDates = ['2013-8-19'];
$(function() {

var today = '2013-08-12';

$( "#datepicker1").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: new Date(today)
});

$( "#datepicker2").datepicker( {
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: new Date(today)
});


$( "#datepicker3").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: new Date(today)
});

$("#dp").click(function(){
    unavailableDates = ['2013-8-24', '2013-8-25'];
    $( "#datepicker2").datepicker( {
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: new Date(today)
    });
});

$("#dp2").click(function(){
    unavailableDates = ['2013-8-20', '2013-8-21', '2013-8-22'];
    $( "#datepicker3").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: new Date(today)
    });
});
});


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1" /></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" /></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker3" /></p>

<button id ="dp">One</button>
<button id ="dp2">Two</button>
```

Comment: You have to use at least two different arrays of unavailable dates and use them accordingly.

Comment: thank you, it will works

Comment: Ok added as answer; if it solves your problem mark it as accepeted

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use array (ex. fecth values from DB or from a web service) you can use this code:

```
function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();

    var unavailableDates;
    switch (this.id) {
        case "datepicker1":
            unavailableDates = unavailableDates1;
            break;
        case "datepicker2":
            unavailableDates = unavailableDates2;
            break;
        case "datepicker3":
            unavailableDates = unavailableDates3;
            break;
    }

    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}
var unavailableDates1 = ['2013-8-19'];
var unavailableDates2 = ['2013-8-19'];
var unavailableDates3 = ['2013-8-19'];
$(function () {

    var today = '2013-08-12';

    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: new Date(today)
    });

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: new Date(today)
    });


    $("#datepicker3").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: new Date(today)
    });

    $("#dp").click(function () {
        unavailableDates2 = ['2013-8-24', '2013-8-25'];
    });

    $("#dp2").click(function () {
        unavailableDates3 = ['2013-8-20', '2013-8-21', '2013-8-22'];
    });
});
```

Consider `thatbeforeShowDay` is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/P6V8a/

Comment: When you change the array, call the `.refresh` method, this will update the display.

Comment: @SalmanA `beforeShowDay` is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed, so it work without any refresh, try on the fiddle

Comment: You're right. My comment applies to "inline datepickers" which are always visible so they explicitly need to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function unavailable(unavailableDates) {
    return function(date){
        var dmy = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }
}
var unavailableDates = ['2013-8-19'];
$(function() {

    var today = '2013-08-12';

    $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable(unavailableDates),
        minDate: new Date(today)
    });

    $("#dp").click(function(){
        $( "#datepicker2").datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', unavailable(['2013-8-24', '2013-8-25']));
    });

    $("#dp2").click(function(){
        $( "#datepicker3").datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', unavailable(['2013-8-20', '2013-8-21', '2013-8-22']));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J2Hjy/)